# ion-progress-bar text

Tags: angular, ionic, ts

Tengo el progress bar pero no me muestra el texto (Es decir el porcentaje de cuanto lleva, ejemplo 10%).

```
<ion-progress-bar [value]="progressValue" style="height: 1em; border-radius: 8px">
<p>{{ progressText }} %</p>
</ion-progress-bar>
```

en el .ts tengo

```
  progressValue: number;
  progressText: string;

  constructor() {
    this.progressValue = 0.044;
    this.calcularProgressText();
  }
  calcularProgressText() {
    this.progressText = this.progressValue + '%';
    console.log( this.progressText)
  }
```

como puedo hacer para mostrar el texto dentro de la barra en el ion-progress-bar?

Answer (score 0):

Directamente no se puede porque el control no tiene esa funcionalidad. Pero se puede hacer de otra forma:

```
<div class="progress-value">
  <ion-progress-bar [value]="progress"></ion-progress-bar>
  <span>18%</span>
</div>
```

Se agrupan el `progress-bar` y el `span` y con css se hace el efecto:

```
.progress-value ion-progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
}

.progress-value span {
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Todo es desplazar el span con el valor del portaje hacia arriba y ya queda sobre el progress-bar. Ahí se puede ajustar al gusto ya el tamaño y posición del texto "dentro" del progress-bar.

Aquí te dejo un [ejemplo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msyxof?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)